# Generating orthomosaic from DEM in Metashape

Tags: dem, alignment, photogrammetry

I'm using Metashape to make a point cloud from georeferenced drone images using the basic workflow (Align photos -> Build Point Cloud). I then export that and align it to a LiDAR cloud we have from before. Now, I want to make an orthomosaic that is the same alignment as the aligned point cloud. I tried simply loading the aligned cloud into Metashape and building the DEM + ortho, but this does not work because Metashape uses the photos as the correct location instead of the cloud.

One workaround I thought about was generating a DEM from the aligned cloud in R, then uploading that as a DEM in Metashape and creating an ortho from that plus the aligned photos. However, I consistently get the "Zero resolution" error, even after following the workflow [here](https://www.agisoft.com/forum/index.php?topic=8412.0). I don't understand because the DEM is in the correct CRS, and I've ensured the chunk is in the correct CRS. However, when I view the DEM, it does not overlay the tie points / photos.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Or recommendation for another way to output a correctly-aligned orthomosaic? I think an alternative would be forcing the photos to align to the point cloud, but I don't know if that's possible. I have already looked at this [other post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/470929/aligning-two-orthophotos-with-metashape) on Stack.